# Is it possible to get hold of free theorems as propositional equalities?

Tags: agda

"Free theorems" in the sense of Wadler's paper "Theorems for Free!" are equations about certain values are derived based only on their type. So that, for example,

```
f : {A : Set} → List A → List A
```

automatically satisfies

```
f . map g = map g . f
```

Can I get my hands on an Agda term, then, of the following type:

```
(f : {A : Set} → List A → List A) {B C : Set} (g : B → C) (xs : List B)
  → f (map g xs) ≡ map g (f xs)
```

or if so/if not, can I do something more/less general?

I'm aware of the existence of the [Lightweight Free Theorems library](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.LightweightFreeTheorems) but I don't think it does what I want (or if it does, I don't understand it well enough to do it).

(An example use case is that I have a functor `F : Set → Set` and would like to prove that a polymorphic function `F A × F B → F (A × B)` is automatically a natural transformation.)

Comment: Better suited for Computer Science sites.

Comment: I disagree – this is a question that is about what is concretely achievable in Agda today, rather than what is abstractly or theoretically possible.

Comment: Everyone wants to get free theorems off the Internet.  That's what's killed the theorem publishing business. ;(

Answer (score 14):

No, the type theory on which Agda is build is not strong enough to prove this. This would require a feature called "internalized parametricity", see the work by Guilhem:

- Jean-Philippe Bernardy and Guilhem Moulin: [*A Computational Interpretation of Parametricity*](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/local_147257.pdf) (2012)
- Guilhem Moulin: [*Pure Type Systems with an Internalized Parametricity Theorem*](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/191873/191873.pdf) (2013)

This would allow you for example to prove that all inhabitants of "(A : Set) → A → A" are equal to the (polymorphic) identity function. As far as I know, this has not been implemented in any language yet.

Comment: Your links 404'd, so I googled the titles and replaced them with new ones.

Comment: Actually, the first one I found was "Towards a computational interpretation of parametricity". Is that the right one?

Comment: It looks like Moulin did his thesis on this in 2016 https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/70616322.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Chantal Keller and Marc Lasson developped a tactic for Coq generating the parametricity relation corresponding to a (closed) type and proving that this type's inhabitants satisfy the generated relation. You can find more details about this work on [Keller's website](http://cs.au.dk/~chkeller/Recherche/coqparam.html).

Now in Agda's case, it is in theory possible to do the same sort of work by implementing the tactic in pure Agda using a technique called reflection.

Comment: Your comment about Agda seems to contradict the other answer – are you sure it is possible?

Comment: Coq does not internalize parametricity either: it's a tactics that does the job. Similarly, neither Agda nor Coq have `fold` functions for their inductive types but you can write a tactic building these iterators automatically. This is true because (and it's a meta-theorem, just like parametricity is) given the restrictions in their type systems, you know that every inductive type has an initial algebra.